# Fortran MPI code causing segmentation fault when using MPI_Scatter

Tags: fortran, mpi

I'm running a calculation in Fortran, and I'm using MPI to parallelise a **do** loop. There are 4 external input arrays(X,Y,zeta_list and M_list) but to make it easier for testing I've used **call random_number** to generate the input arrays. I use MPI_Scatter to distribute the elements in the array **zeta_list**, which the loop runs over.

```
PROGRAM TEST_MPI

use mpi

IMPLICIT NONE 

DOUBLE PRECISION,DIMENSION(1,10)::M_list
DOUBLE PRECISION,DIMENSION(11,11)::X,Y,z_m_z_x,z_m_z_y,dist_z_m_z,alpha_x, alpha_y, sub_alpha_x, sub_alpha_y
DOUBLE PRECISION,DIMENSION(2,10)::zeta_list
DOUBLE PRECISION,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:,:)::sub_zeta_list
INTEGER::i,myid,ntasks,ierror,n_elements,chunk 


call MPI_INIT(ierror)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierror)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ntasks, ierror)


if (myid == 0) then 
    call random_number(X)
    call random_number(Y)
    call random_number(zeta_list)
    call random_number(M_list)
    alpha_x = 0
    alpha_y = 0 
    sub_alpha_x = 0 
    sub_alpha_y = 0 
    z_m_z_x = 0
    z_m_z_y = 0 
    dist_z_m_z = 0 
end if 
n_elements = size(zeta_list,1)*size(zeta_list,2)
chunk = n_elements/ntasks
allocate(sub_zeta_list(2,chunk/2))
sub_zeta_list = 0 

call MPI_Scatter(zeta_list,chunk,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,sub_zeta_list,chunk,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD)

do i=1,chunk/2,1
        z_m_z_x = X - sub_zeta_list(1,i)
        z_m_z_y = Y - sub_zeta_list(2,i)
        dist_z_m_z = z_m_z_x**2 + z_m_z_y**2
        sub_alpha_x = sub_alpha_x + (M_list(1,i)* z_m_z_x / dist_z_m_z)
end do

call MPI_REDUCE(sub_alpha_x,alpha_x,121,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierror)    

if (myid == 0) then
    write(*,*)alpha_x
end if 

call MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)
stop
END PROGRAM TEST_MPI
```

When I compile with mpif90 -g test.f90 and do mpirun -np 1 a.out, I get the following. Line 39 is where I use my MPI_Scatter, and I've checked the array sizes. What could be going wrong with my Scatter function? I'm thinking maybe this is happening because the input array zeta_list is 2D, but I'm not entirely sure. Would appreciate any help!

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F1EC6382E08
#1  0x7F1EC6381F90
#2  0x7F1EC5FD24AF
#3  0x7F1EC66BC857
#4  0x401225 in MAIN__ at test9.f90:39

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 9284 RUNNING AT juggernaut
=   EXIT CODE: 139
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault (signal 11)
This typically refers to a problem with your application.
Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

Comment: You need to allocate `sub_zeta_list`. My Fortran is bad, but I'm pretty sure you don't.  Also 99% sure this is a duplicate question.

Comment: you mean I don't need to allocate sub_zeta_list? And I posted a similar question before, but I was told to re-write it in a clearer and testable way, so I deleted the previous one

Comment: Yes, you need to have the receive buffer allocated on all processes.  You allocate it on only one.

Comment: Oh so do you mean I just do the allocate(sub_zeta_list(2,chunk/2)) outside the if(myid==0) loop? Tried this and still same error

Comment: But you aren't setting the value of `chunk`, for the size for the allocation, for those other ranks.

Comment: If you mean like how I've written down the edited code, it still doesn't work.

Comment: FWIW I do not get any crash for any number of processes with your current code. Gfortran 4.8.5, Linux 64bit, OpenMPI 1.10.3.

Comment: After a lot of trouble going through different mpi packages, the code runs on OpenMPI...seems like my MPICH has/had some issue, and I had to reinstall the libraries and tried with OpenMPI instead. Weird that MPICH provides an error...still can't seem to figure out why